# How to develop the iPhone Widget so that they can be run even if the app is in background state

Tags: iphone, widget, feasibility

I need to develop widgets for the iphone device. But don't know how to do it. Are they possible to develop & acceptable as per the apple norms?

Basically I need develop an app which can display its view also when the phone is locked or app is in Background mode.

I mean the app view will always on the top of the screen immaterial that the app is in active state or in background mode

Is this possible?

I am not sure about it so please guide me with the better option to achieve the same

Thanks & Regards,

Zahur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using the iOS SDK. It *may* be possible on a jailbroken device, but there is a 0% chance that it would make it into the App Store.

Answer (score 3):

It's only possible for jailbroken devices. Apple has no public APIs that allow you to display things other than push/local alerts on the lock screen or home screen.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible?

Nope